# Pager icons gets a pixel shift when enabled

Tags: css, jqgrid

Pager icons in jqgrid move/shift from their place. I tried to change `css` like:

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-corner-all:hover{
   padding:0px 1px;
}
```

This works when `next/back` pager icons are disabled. But when the pager icons get enabled, they have a pixel shift. How to prevent this shift?

I am using jqGrid version `4.6.0`

Comment: could you verify that the problem exist in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) too? I made many changes in CSS and included settings on `.ui-state-disabled:hover` too. You need just temporary change the URLs to jqGrid files to URLs described [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). If the same problem exists in free jqGrid, I will examine the problem. Please describe it more detailed: which web browser you use in your tests, which zoom you have in the tests (one should verify whether the problem exist with 100% or 200% zoom).

Comment: @Oleg I just changed the css file to the one at https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid but it still gives the problem. The zoom level is 100%. I am using chrome.

Comment: Do you changed **only CSS** or the JS files too? Which web browser you used in your tests? Could you provide the demo which reproduce the problem? [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons0.htm) or [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons0-fa4.htm) have no problems.

Comment: @Oleg I just changed the `CSS` file. I am using chrome. I am sorry, it will be very tough to replicate the issue. I am using jquery ui that runs in cooperation with bootstrap.

Comment: @Oleg They don't move when when the icons are disabled as in http://s16.postimg.org/ncp4cnlk5/Capture.png but move when enabled http://s18.postimg.org/ulnzppxsp/Capture1.png Earlier, they moved even when in disabled state, so I wrote : `.ui-jqgrid .ui-corner-all:hover{
 padding:0px 1px;
}` and it stopped but not for the enabled state.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you if you don't provide the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem. To solve the problem one have to analyse the demo with respect of Developer Tools. Try with http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/kvtrtzc5/3/ for example and modify it to youth. To change the icons you need remove `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option.

Comment: @Oleg I was finally able to solve the problem by this css : http://pastebin.com/KG11E1xM